# atualizar repositorio remoto com as mudanças feitas em repositório local

Tags: git, github

eu atualizei o meu repositório local com novas informações e desejo atualizar meu repositório remoto com essas mudanças? quais comandos devo utilizar para conseguir esse objetivo? estou usando o git bash do windows.

Comment: `git push <origem> <branch>`

Comment: nossa muito obrigado mas fiquei com duvida de qual seria esse caminho do origem eu não sei exatamente qual o link do main no github

Comment: maravilha consegui muito obrigado!